# chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python

Hi I m actually having this error, I did already read some other questions, but didn't find them so helpful.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Download driver and give the path according to where it saved

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

```
webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="your path")
```

Comment: driver = webdriver.Chrome('executable_path=C:/Users/ranie/Downloads')    . i did thi excatly , but it gives me the same error

Comment: you have to mention file name with extension (executable_path="C:/Users/ranie/Downloads/chromedriver.exe")

Comment: i did it too ...

Comment: What about backslashes? `C:\Users\ranie\Downloads\chromedriver.exe`